# Packages not found in current channels for Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to download a package called `ont-tombo` for DNA sequencing analysis through the **bioconda** channel, but although the package is listed as belonging to the channel, it isn't able to find it. I am running the following code through Anaconda to try and install the package:

```
conda install -c bioconda ont-tombo
```

But I keep getting the same error message:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels
```

I do have all three of the necessary channels configured (**conda-forge**, **bioconda**, and **defaults**), so I don't think it's an issue with the channels. For more information on the package, it is [available on the bioconda website](https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/ont-tombo/README.html#package-ont-tombo).

Any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: What is the OS? Bioconda does not support Windows.

Comment: If you are on Windows, there is always [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and install Miniforge (not Anaconda).